# What to do in Triage to agree with a duplicate flag when you can't cast a close vote

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

Reading [this Triage queue review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6468296), I saw a "Possible duplicate" comment from another user. It looks to me like that judgment is correct, and I upvoted the comment. However, I still have to choose an option to complete the Triage review.

I'm pretty confident based on the commenting user's reputation score and the formatting of the comment that the question's already been sent to the close queue. So it seems there's nothing left for me to do.

If I click "Unsalvageable" I'll be forced to cast another flag. Would this be in any way productive? To my knowledge, once the question's already queued for closing, another flag of the same type would have no real consequence.

I hesitate to cast flags needlessly, so I skipped the item. Is there a better response?

Comment: If casting another flag would have no real consequence, why not cast the flag? I always pick the most appropriate option based on the question/answer alone, without looking at anyone else's actions.

Comment: It's hard to keep straight which flags pop up and annoy moderators vs. which just send things to queues.

Comment: AFAIK, anything where you have to type something when flagging is going to annoy a moderator. Everything else is fair game. Now watch this comment annoy a moderator ;).

Comment: I usually flag them as well.  Though they always come back *disputed* - despite still being closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The correct action is to go ahead and flag it just like you would have if you didn't know somebody else already had. Identical flags on the same posts don't cause any more work for moderators as handling them is done in a single action, and the extra a list of names that have reviewed and agreed on a situation makes it that much easier to handle.

Comment: There actually *is* a subtle effect on the system as well: posts with multiple flags get additional emphasis in various queues.